# pintar respuesta con ejs

Tags: nodejs, express, ejs

tengo el siguiente codigo(estoy haciendo un app que muestre el clima), mi problema es que cuando hago el res.render, no me toma la variable "temperature" para pintarla en el html ejs, queria preguntarles como podria hacerlo, muchas gracias

```
  https.get(apiURL,function(response){
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    
    response.on("data",function(data){
        let weatherData = JSON.parse(data);
        let temperature = weatherData.main.temp;
        console.log(temp)
    }) 
    
})
res.render('weather',{temperatura_ejs:temperature})
```

Comment: Problema de asincronía, mueve la línea `res.render` dentro de la función *callback* que pasas al evento `on` de tu objeto `response`, justo donde tienes tu `console.log()`. Comenta el resultado. Saludos

Comment: Si me resulto muchas gracias mauricio!!